# How to alert / see log in mysql

Tags: mysql, logging, alert

This is very basic MySQL question.

I am writing MySQL procedure, using MySQL workbench, I wish to test it, but I don't know how to print alert or log on the screen.

How do I do that?

Comment: Just `SELECT 'message'`.

Comment: @eggyal tnx eggyal, this is what I been looking for, sorry that I can't mark you as the current answer.

Comment: I have posted as an answer.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `SELECT 'message'` to have `message` appear in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: the only limitation is that you can only select once. so if you got many logs need to collect them to buffer and select in the end

Comment: @Babibu: That shouldn't be the case - the results of multiple `SELECT` statements should each appear in Workbench.

Comment: just test it and you will see. Write select("test 1"); select("test 2"). it will only show the last one